# Prove that $A$ is similar to $B$ probably using Jordan form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

Let $A, B \in M_n(\mathbb{F})$ such that:

1. $a_{ij} = 0 \iff b_{ij} = 0$.
2. $a_{ij} = b_{ij}$ for all $i \ne j+1$
3. $\exists \lambda \in \mathbb{F}$ such that $a_{ii} = b_{ii} = \lambda$.

> Prove that $A$ and $B$ are similar matrices.

This question should be related (I think) to the Jordan form material. 
I'd be glad for any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've mis-stated some of your conditions.  As I understand them, the following two matrices satisfy your three conditions but they are not similar:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 2 \end{bmatrix} \qquad \text{and} \qquad \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: That's weird...

Comment: I suspect that the conditions are *supposed* to result in a matrix that's almost in Jordan normal form, except the entries on the sub-diagonal aren't all $1$.  In that case all you need to do is scale the basis elements to turn those entries into $1$'s, so if two matrices of that type had the same block sizes then they would indeed be similar.